# Xcode 12 run issue

Tags: xcode12

Executable Not Found

XXX.app is not a valid path to an executable file. Please rebuild the project to ensure that all required executables are created. Check your project settings to ensure that a valid executable will be built.

Comment: Can't really help without more details. What kind of executable are you building? Have you tried cleaning and building? Have you tried clearing derived data?